# Latest WPML updates broke my wordpress post categories and menus

Tags: plugin-wpml

After the latests wpml plugin updates my website is acting weird. It seems that somehow lost post categories, menus and other functionalities. If i go to post categories nothing comes up. I see that there are "English (6) | Greek (31) | All languages (37)" categories but after this i get "No categories found". If i go to menu administration i see that there are no menu created but in the front-end both English and Greek menu is fine. I tried every cleanup action in wpml's troubleshooting page but nothing fixed it. I tried to change manual in database a post category in brkw_term_taxonomy table which it seems that worked fine but now my database is broken. When i am trying to update any post content i receive an Internal Server Error with the following log:

```
WordPress database error Table 'wp_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist for query SELECT key1.term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy key1 INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships key2 on key2.term_taxonomy_id = key1.term_taxonomy_id and key1.taxonomy = 'category' INNER JOIN wp_posts key3 on key3.id = key2.object_id and key3.post_content LIKE '%torrent%' made by wp_dropdown_categories, get_terms, apply_filters('terms_clauses'), call_user_func_array, ex_cats, W3_Db->query, W3_DbCache->query, W3_DbCallUnderlying->query, W3_Db->query, W3_DbProcessor->query, W3_Db->default_query
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND ( ( icl_t.element_type IN ('tax_category')  AND icl_t.language_code = 'el'' at line 3 for query SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM brkw_terms AS t INNER JOIN brkw_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id LEFT JOIN brkw_icl_translations icl_t ON icl_t.element_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id AND icl_t.element_type = CONCAT('tax_', tt.taxonomy) WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND t.term_id NOT IN() AND ( ( icl_t.element_type IN ('tax_category')  AND icl_t.language_code = 'el') OR icl_t.element_type NOT IN ('tax_category') OR icl_t.element_type IS NULL )  ORDER BY t.name ASC  made by wp_dropdown_categories, get_terms, W3_Db->query, W3_DbCache->query, W3_DbCallUnderlying->query, W3_Db->query, W3_DbProcessor->query, W3_Db->default_query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was a bad plugin installed in my site called WPCore3 by Lososev. I deleted it and now everything works fine...